# Jquery calendar with multiple months and with event support

Tags: jquery, calendar

I have been searching for a jquery plugin that is capable of

1. Showing multiple months.
2. Allow developer to add custom events on days, edit template of days to make the day/event customizable.

I have gone through [Cldnr.js](http://kylestetz.github.io/CLNDR/)
and the jquery calendar plugin, but it seems that it is bit complex to extend these or it is not at all possible. I have also seen people achieving multiple months functionality by having more than one calendar, but this does not seem to be a solution to me.

Any links to a possible plugin that can provide both the functions would be very helpful.

Comment: Searching too... Would update soon if i find something intresting.